# Error while running flutter run command in command prompt : [Fatal Error] aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: gradle, aapt2

flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 8A Dual in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[Fatal Error] aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

- What went wrong:
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Required by:
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> project :app
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.
> 5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

- Try:
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
  output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
BUILD FAILED in 4m 36s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       284.7s (!)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1